Is the coboundary of a non-abelian cochain a cocycle?
Let $G$ and $H$ be groups (written multiplicatively), with $G$ acting trivially on $H$. Let $A\leq Z(H)$ be a subgroup of the centre of $H$. Let $f:G^n\to H$ ($n\geq1$) be any set-theoretic map. Morally my question is the following, and a more precise formulation is developed subsequently.

View $f$ as an inhomogeneous 'non-abelian $n$-cochain', and consider its coboundary $\delta f$. If the image of $\delta f$ lies in $A$, do we have $\delta^2f=1$?

Now, let me address the ambiguity in the above. It is not clear how $\delta f$ must be interpreted, since one needs to pick the order of the terms in the usual formula used in group cohomology. Let's suppose this order is chosen using some fixed permutation, by which I mean the following. Pick a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{0,\ldots,n+1\}$, and define $f_i:G^{n+1}\to H$ ($0\leq i\leq n+1$) by
$$f_i(g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1})=\begin{cases}
f(g_2,\ldots,g_{n+1}) & i=0\\
f(g_1,\ldots,\hat{g_i},g_ig_{i+1},g_{i+2},\ldots,g_{n+1}) & i>0.
\end{cases}$$
Let $\delta_\sigma f:G^{n+1}\to H$ be the '$\sigma$-coboundary' of $f$, given by
$$\delta_\sigma f=\prod_{i=0}^{n+1} \left(f_{\sigma(i)}\right)^{(-1)^{\sigma(i)}}.$$
If $H$ were abelian, then this is just the usual coboundary of $f$ written in multiplicative notation. Hence, the formal version of my question is the following.

If the image of $\delta_\sigma f$ lies in $A$, then $\delta_\sigma f$ is an $(n+1)$-cochain in the usual sense. Is it also a cocycle, i.e. do we have $\delta \delta_\sigma f=1$? Does the answer depend on $n$ or $\sigma$?

ETA: The case I care about most is $n=2$. Of course, for any fixed $n$ one can answer the question using a brute-force computation (at least if the answer is affirmative), but what I am interested in is whether there is a more elegant way to go about it. Also, for $n=1$, note that the 'brute-force computation' in question is essentially done as part of the standard proof that the second group cohomology is in bijection with central extensions.
